# How do I create a role programmatically?

Tags: 8, users, installation

How do I create a role programmatically?

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::create(['id' => 'client', 'name' => 'Client']);
$role->save();
```

Comment: I update my answer ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer : I would edit my answer to incorporate those PHP version comments also (5.6, 5.5.9, drupal 8, etc) ... Would make your answer way easier to digest. But of course, that's your choice ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens If you want to edit your answer, I don't know which answer, because here there is only one, but if you want edit my answer go ahead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is in the data array change *name* by *label*:

```
$role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::create(array('id' => 'client', 'label' => 'Client'));
$role->save();
```

Or you can use:

```
//your data array
$data = array('id' => 'client', 'label' => 'Client');
//creating your role
$role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::create($data);
//saving your role
$role->save();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try this an let you know. Hmm I find it quite odd that Drupal 8 lets you return array as such but not pass them.... Never mind still learning Drupal 8 cheers!!!

Comment: Adrian has just separated the lines out so the comments can show you what's going on @Jake, usually the one-liner from your original question would be fine

Comment: Thanks @Clive That's the point just show another way ;-)

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, didn't see the first revision of the answer - @Jake, as long as you're using >= php5.4 the short array syntax will work (Drupal doesn't change how php itself works)

Comment: I understood that ;) thanks I will try and find an example of what I mean, thanks all! I will mark as correct when I've done a test

Comment: @JakeLacey I change the array definition because if there is a user with php < 5.4 the code doesn't work ;-)

Comment: @JakeLacey I test the code and it works ;-)

Comment: @Adrian Drupal 8 will not work with php <5.6 ;)

Comment: @alexej_d thanks for the info, I don't have read the requirements yet

Comment: @alexej_d Drupal 8 don't work with php < 5.5.9, https://www.drupal.org/requirements, and thanks again, I reading the requirements now ;-)

Comment: @JakeLacey a pleasure and good luck in your projects ;-)

Comment: @JakeLacey  Can you please explain where should i put the code and where i can run it ? Sorry i'm new to Drupal. Many thanks

Comment: @usethe23 It depends, what do you want to do and where?

Comment: I want to be able to create new roles programmatically, i need to create 20 roles, so i want to find a way to do this without using the interface, i don't know how to use the code, where do i put it and how can i run it ? Many thanks

Comment: @usethe23 is better if you create a new question in the site. If you do it let my know here!

Comment: I already did : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226366/create-new-roles-programatically-in-drupal-8