# Where do I programmatically create new roles?

Tags: 8, users

I want to programmatically create new roles in Drupal 8. I found this code in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183969/how-do-i-create-a-role-programmatically).

```
//your data array
$data = array('id' => 'client', 'label' => 'Client');
//creating your role
$role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::create($data);
//saving your role
$role->save();
```

But I don't know where I should put it, in which file, which folder? And how do I run it?

Comment: when you need to create the roles?

Comment: I have a list of roles and i want to create them, When ? Now

Comment: I don't want to do anything else, just create the roles

Comment: You can do it when a module gets installed with hook_install, or you can choose to put it in a hook_update_n function. It's up to you. Don't "just" run code once that changes the db, because you will lose installability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many place to create your roles, a simple way for you (As you says that [you don't know nothing about Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183969/how-do-i-create-a-role-programmatically#comment276444_183970)) can be [create a custom page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-page) (read the post) if you follow the example in the `myPage()` function you can go trough your list of roles and create each role in a loop, something like this;

```
public function myPage() {
...
  /* Read your roles
   * $my_roles[0]['id'] = 'client';
   * $my_roles[0]['label'] = 'My Client';
   */
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_roles); $i++) {
    //your data array
    $data = array('id' => $my_roles[$i]['id'], 'label' => $my_roles[$i]['label']);
    //creating your role
    $role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::create($data);
    //saving your role
    $role->save();
  }
...
}
```

And if you go to your page you will create your roles.

**EDIT:** As [Kevin says](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226366/create-new-roles-programatically-in-drupal-8?noredirect=1#comment276457_226370) is better in other places like the [hook_install()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/8.2.x)

Follow the steps to [create a module](http://www.codementality.com/blog/drupal-8-development-part-2-scaffolding-module) and implement the `hook_install()` (Read at the end of the [page](http://www.codementality.com/blog/drupal-8-development-part-2-scaffolding-module) how to do it)

Inside the hook implementation you will put the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_install() {
    /* Read your roles
     * $my_roles[0]['id'] = 'client';
     * $my_roles[0]['label'] = 'My Client';
     */
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_roles); $i++) {
      //your data array
      $data = array('id' => $my_roles[$i]['id'], 'label' => $my_roles[$i]['label']);
      //creating your role
      $role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::create($data);
      //saving your role
      $role->save();
    }
}
```

To create your roles you only need install your module.